# Template for a function multiple arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
class EventDispatcher {
public:

    template <typename T...> void on(std::string eventID, void(*f)(T...) callback);

    template <typename T...> void trigger(std::string eventID, T&... args);
}

//...

void doSomething(int a, float b, SomeObject c){...}

// ...

eventDispatcher.on("someEvent", doSomething);

// ...

eventDispatcher.trigger("someEvent", a, b, c);
```

So I'd like T to be multiple arguments, and that the `eventDispatcher#trigger` can access them. **How can the implementation of trigger access these args?**

EDIT:

My new class

```
template <typename T...> class EventDispatcher {
public:

    EventDispatcher(std::string eventID);

    void on(std::function<void(T...)> callback);

    void trigger(T&... args);

};
template<typename T...> void registerListener(std::string eventID, std::function<void(T...)> callback);
template<typename T...> void invokeListener(std::string eventID, T.. args);
std::vector<EventDispatcher<>> dispatchers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the syntax wrong. First, the template should be the class `EventDispatcher`, not the individual functions. Second, the `...` are misplaced:

```
template <typename... T>
class EventDispatcher {
public:
    void on(std::string eventID, void (*f)(T...) callback);
    void trigger(std::string eventID, T... args);
};
```

If you make the member functions as template, instead of the class, then there will be no connection between the arguments of one and the other. I don't think that will be wise.

An implementation might be like this:

```
private:
    std::vector<void (*f)(T...)> m_callbacks;
public:
    void on(std::string eventID, void (*f)(T...) callback)
    {   //eventID left as an exercise to the reader
        m_callbacks.push_back(callback);
    }
    void trigger(std::string eventID, T... args)
    {
        for (auto f : m_callbacks)
            f(args...);
    }
```

Comment: I've got a terrible feeling in a moment we're going to see a "somOtherEvent" with different parameters rear its head on the same dispatcher.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Now it compiles correctly, but how can the implementation access them. So give me a moment, I'll try to make the class as template

Comment: @Vinz243: I've added some sample code. But note that the code will be more useful if, instead of `void (*f)(T...)` you use `std::function<void(T...)>`.

Comment: Thank, you, exactly what I wanted :) I've just corrected the header, is better now?

Comment: @Vinz243: Quite... but in the template header it should be `...T`, while in the body it is `T...` and `args...`. Maybe you compiler accepts it as you wrote?

Comment: No it didn't. And that's why I got 60 errors. thank you!

Comment: However, in my impl it tells me `Error C2990: 'EventDispatcher' : non-class template has already been declared as a class template`

Comment: It's fixed. How can I do something like that? `std::map<std::string, EventDispatcher>` with event dispatchers taking anything